# Rust 'for loop' (converting from c++)

Tags: rust

Trying to convert this for loop from c++ to rust and i'm having a hard time figuring it out as I'm very new to Rust syntax.

```cpp
double sinError = 0;
for (float x = -10 * M_PI; x < 10 * M_PI; x += M_PI / 300) {
    double approxResult = sin_approx(x);
    double libmResult = sinf(x);
    sinError = MAX(sinError, fabs(approxResult - libmResult));
}
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt? What particular bit are you stuck on?

Comment: The easiest solution is to convert this to a `while` loop, which works roughly the same in Rust and C++.

Comment: Iterating over `float`s that way is probably a bad idea (regardless of language); you accumulate some amount of rounding error every time you add /300 to `x`. If the `x` values should be evenly spaced, what you usually want is to iterate over an integer range and multiply each value by a scalar, like `for x in (-3000..3000).map(|i| (i as f32)*PI/300.0) {...}`

Comment: Aloso, that's what I figured as well and what I have done in the short term. Was curious if there was a way to replicate the for loop. Thanks.

Also, that's good info, trenctl. Thank you.

Comment: @blindside044 There is, by using `std::iter::successors` and `Iterator::take_while`. But I agree with @trentcl that iterating over integers would be better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Iterate over integers

As @trentcl already pointed out, it's usually better to iterate over integers instead of floats, to prevent numerical errors from adding up:

```rust
use std::f32::consts::PI;

let mut sin_error = 0.0;

for x in (-3000..3000).map(|i| (i as f32) * PI / 300.0) {
    sin_error = todo!();
}
```

Just replace `todo!()` with the code that computes the next `sin_error`.

#### A more functional way

```rust
use std::f32::consts::PI;

let sin_error = (-3000..3000)
    .map(|i| (i as f32) * PI / 300.0)
    .fold(0.0, |sin_error, x| todo!());
```

In case you don't care about numerical errors, or want to iterate over something else, here are some other options:

## Use a `while` loop

It's not as nice, but does the job!

```rust
use std::f32::consts::PI;

let mut sin_error = 0.0;
let mut x = -10.0 * PI;

while (x < 10.0 * PI) {
    sin_error = todo!();
    x += PI / 300.0;
}
```

## Create your iterator with `successors()`

The `successors()` function creates a new iterator where each successive item is computed based on the preceding one:

```rust
use std::f32::consts::PI;
use std::iter::successors;

let mut sin_error = 0.0;

let iter = successors(Some(-10.0 * PI), |x| Some(x + PI / 300.0));

for x in iter.take_while(|&x| x < 10.0 * PI) {
    sin_error = todo!();
}
```

#### A more functional way

```rust
use std::f32::consts::PI;
use std::iter::successors;

let sin_error = successors(Some(-10.0 * PI), |x| Some(x + PI / 300.0))
   .take_while(|&x| x < 10.0 * PI)
   .fold(0.0, |sin_error, x| todo!());
```